# Django redirect to page with new context

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

I have this bit of code:

```
{% for i in list %}
<button>{{i}}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I redirect to a new page and pass it value of `i` as a context, so that it will be like this:

```
<h3> You chose {{i}} </h3>
```

It doesn't have to be a button, in fact I'd prefer if it could be `<span>` with sort of the same functionality as in AngularJS `ng-click`

Do I need to send a request with button click and then handle it in `views.py`? Can I do this without a form?
I would prefer if it just redirected me to `.../page?i='whatever'`
I can do it with

`<span><a href=".../page?i={{i}}">Click</a></span>`

But what's the preferred Django way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to send a request with button click and then handle it in
>   views.py?

Yes , you would need to create a view to handle that request that will be of type `GET` and will have data i inside it.

> Can I do this without a form?

Yes of course you can and hence your approach of making it a link rather than a button is better and is the way it should/is done in most of the cases. But there is nothing Djangoish in this approach , its just the way it should be done...

> I would prefer if it just redirected me to .../page?i='whatever' I can
>   do it with

Go ahead and do this way its fine.

```
<span><a href=".../page?i={{i}}">Click</a></span>
```

> How do I redirect to a new page and pass it value of i as a context, so that it will be like this `<h3> You chose {{i}} </h3>`:

```
def link(request):
 i = request.GET.get('i',None)
 render_to_response('your_html_template', {"i": i}, RequestContext(request))
```